# Importing gmail, yahoo, hotmail address book using social auth

Tags: gmail, yahoo, addressbook, hotmail, socialauth

How can I import email providers address book using social auth?

When I try to get the contact details, I get the email field as null.
Can someone help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  You should edit yout post and show us the code you have tried.  THat would allow others to help you faster.